# Circular dependency when using dnf?

Tags: ubuntu, dnf

I'm trying to install the Smart Cam App on a Kria Kv260 running Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop. 
A part of the installation is to run: 
`sudo dnf install packagegroup-kv260-smartcam.noarch`
but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
ubuntu@kria:~$ sudo dnf install packagegroup-kv260-smartcam.noarch
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dnf/const.py:22: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  import distutils.sysconfig
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dnf/const.py:22: DeprecationWarning: The distutils.sysconfig module is deprecated, use sysconfig instead
  import distutils.sysconfig
Unable to detect release version (use '--releasever' to specify release version)
Error: There are no enabled repositories in "/etc/yum.repos.d", "/etc/yum/repos.d", "/etc/distro.repos.d".
```

I quickly found out via Googling that to create a repo you need the `createrepo` package and to enable one you need the `config-manager` package but both of these packages are only installable through `dnf`.

How would I solve this?

Comment: *A part of the installation is to run* what instructions are you following?

Comment: Not sure if it would affect the installation in any way, but  https://www.xilinx.com/products/som/kria/kv260-vision-starter-kit/kv260-getting-started/trying-the-smart-camera-app.html is my installation source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be running Ubuntu, but are attempting to install a RPM package with `dnf`.  While you can get `dnf` running within Ubuntu, I do not believe you are able to use it to manage package installs within the Ubuntu system.

Your current error is `Error: There are no enabled repositories in "/etc/yum.repos.d", "/etc/yum/repos.d", "/etc/distro.repos.d"`.  Once you enable repositories that have the dependencies for the package you are attempting to install, it would be unlikely that those packages would be able to be installed because the packages were built for `dnf/rpm` based distributions.

Ubuntu uses `apt/dpkg` for its own package management.  Unless you can find a `.deb` package or an `aptitude` repository for that software, you may be better off trying to run this on a supported distribution.

I did a quick Google search, and found the manufacture seems to have [custom Ubuntu images available with all the necessary software installed](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/2363129857/Getting+Started+with+Certified+Ubuntu+22.04+LTS+for+Xilinx+Devices) so you could just use those directly or use them to figure out how to install the desired software.